# installation errors for Perl Spreadsheet::Write

Tags: excel, perl, installation, spreadsheet, strawberry-perl

I'm trying to install Spreadsheet::Write using Strawberry Perl but getting an error. Please help if you can.

perl -v reports

```
This is perl 5, version 32, subversion 1 (v5.32.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
```

Spreadsheet::Write is failing the tests with the error message "Spreadsheet data does not match reference for 'csv'":

```
Running make test for AMALTSEV/Spreadsheet-Write-1.03.tar.gz
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/all_tests.t .. ====== Expected:
Column1,Column#2,"Column 3","Column  4"
1,"Cell #2/1",C.3/1,"C.4/1/Γÿ║"
2,"Cell #2/2",C.3/2,"C.4/2/Γÿ║"
======
====== Expected:
Column1,Column#2,"Column 3","Column  4"
1,"Cell #2/1",C.3/1,"C.4/1/Γÿ║"
2,"Cell #2/2",C.3/2,"C.4/2/Γÿ║"
======
# t\tlib/Common.pm:79 - WriteCSVTest(test_text_format)
# Boolean assertion failed
# Spreadsheet data does not match reference for 'csv'
#  at t\tlib/Common.pm line 79, <DATA> line 1.
#       Common::spreadsheet_test(WriteCSVTest=HASH(0x2686580), "csv", GLOB(0x2692390)) called at t\tlib/WriteCSVTest.pm line 15
#       WriteCSVTest::test_text_format(WriteCSVTest=HASH(0x2686580)) called at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Test/Unit/Lite.pm line 602
#       eval {...} called at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Test/Unit/Lite.pm line 601
#       Test::Unit::TestSuite::run(Test::Unit::TestSuite=HASH(0x2685e30), Test::Unit::Result=HASH(0x2685e60), Test::Unit::HarnessUnit=HASH(0x78a960)) called at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Test/Unit/Lite.pm line 750
#       Test::Unit::TestRunner::start(Test::Unit::HarnessUnit=HASH(0x78a960), "Test::Unit::Lite::AllTests") called at t/all_tests.t line 23
t/all_tests.t .. Failed 1/3 subtests
```

Comment: For reference, this module uses internally [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV), ref [source line](https://metacpan.org/release/AMALTSEV/Spreadsheet-Write-1.03/source/lib/Spreadsheet/Write/WriteCSV.pm#L6) to write CSV files, ...

Comment: [Excel::Writer::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX), ref [source line](https://metacpan.org/release/AMALTSEV/Spreadsheet-Write-1.03/source/lib/Spreadsheet/Write/WriteXLSX.pm#L4) to write XLSX files, and

Comment: and [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel), ref [source line](https://metacpan.org/release/AMALTSEV/Spreadsheet-Write-1.03/source/lib/Spreadsheet/Write/WriteXLS.pm#L5) to write XLS files. Maybe you could try use one of those modules directly instead?

Comment: There is also [Spreadsheet::Wright](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::Wright) that you could try

Comment: I got Excel::Writer::XLSX working in my code. Thanks.